# Relationship crashing lookups

Tags: relationship, powerpivot

Consider two tables:

1. **T1** with Product | Name | AvgMonthQSold this is the 'one' table
2. **T2** : Products | fcstMonth | fcstQuantity | fcstType {Regular Sales/Promotion: Name of the promotion} this the 'many' table, i.e. many months many quantities many promos etc...

I create a relationship one-to-many, set up a pivot table with

1. **rows**: T1.Product  second level T2.fcstType
2. **columns**: T2.fcstMonth
3. **Values**: T2.fcstQuantity

That's working fine, as I expect for each products I see the forecasted quantities for each month splitted by forecast type, great. 
Then I came with the idea to see in the same table the value of the average monthly quantities of a given product (AvgMonthQSold), to check easily the forecasts, so I add to value field of the pivot table: **T1.AvgMonthQSold**, but then all the T2.fcstType are listed in rows and the AvgMonthQSold is repeated in every row. I was expecting that the product field will still keep the filter context and the fcstType will be for each given product and not a ' cartesian' product (under Product all the fcstType are listed even those which are not related to the 'parent' product) it looks like the value fields from T1 'demultiplies' rows related to T2

Is this related to this issue? [Filter can't flow up hill?](https://powerpivotpro.com/2014/08/filters-can-flow-up-hill-via-formulas-that-is/) It's really difficult to name this problem for a effective 'google' search, I don't understand what's happening, could someone direct me to a link on this topic? For my problem I should either create a related column in T2 with AvgMonthQSold pulled from T1 or use a filter/calculated 'combo' to obtain what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to find a solution, it's really simple (this surprise me), I create a calculated measure in the second table (T2) together with a smart filter check (for presentation purpose, I just want to see values for a product):

`IF( NOT(ISFILTERED (T2[fcstType])); sum(T1[Avg_QMSales]))`

and that all, I get in T2 both the forecast quantity and the value of average month Sales for a given product (the `sum` is in fact the sole value because no aggregation occurs in the T1 table - i.e the 'one' table) 
Even if I am not 100% sure I think that my problem was related to the "Filter can't flow up hill" issue.